# Definition or un/ordered list?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm in doubt whether this is a definition list or an un/ordered list. I would say an un/ordered list but on the other side, it could be a definition list with the product name as a key and the price as a value.
Does anyone know which I should choose if you're looking at the sematics?

```
<dl>
    <dt>Product name 1</dt>
    <dd>price</dd>
    <dt>Product name 2</dt>
    <dd>price</dd>
</dl>
```

Or

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <span>Product name 1</span>
        <span>price</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Product name 2</span>
        <span>price</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What’s the context here? It doesn’t appear to be a list of products (like in a web shop), right? Is name and price the only data about each product? Are the names linked?

Comment: It is a shopping basket of a hotel. It contains the name of the room and its price. It can also contain upsell, such as breakfast for example. It will then probably look like this:


<dl>
    <dt>Comfort room</dt>
    <dd>
        € 100,00
        <dl>
            <dt>Breakfast</dt>
            <dd>€ 15,00<dd>
            <dt>Mini-bar</dt>
            <dd>€ 10,00<dd>
        </dl>     
    </dd>
</dl>

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl):

> The HTML `<dl>` element represents a description list. The element
>   encloses a list of groups of terms (specified using the  element)
>   and descriptions (provided by  elements). Common uses for this
>   element are to implement a glossary or to display metadata (a **list
>   of key-value pairs**).

Looking at the semantics you should use `<dl>`, but from my experience I'm telling you to choose whichever you feel most comfortable with!